# MySQL INSERT is only inserted the first row of foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I'm having a bit of trouble with a foreach loop in PHP. I'm trying to insert a bunch of values from a html form. The way the table in the form works is that the user is able to add a row if they want to. For whatever reason, the foreach loop is only inserting the first row of the table and after a few hours I can't seem to find a solution.

Below is the foreach loop:

```html
$sql = "INSERT INTO map_input (user_id, point_desc, lat, lon) VALUES ";

//inserting into the map_input table
foreach($_GET['input_Lat'] as $i => $Lat)
{
 //get values from form
 $in_Desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['input_Desc'][$i]);
 $Lat = mysql_real_escape_string($Lat);
 $Lon = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['input_Lon'][$i]);
 
 $sql = $sql."('$user_id', '$in_Desc', '$Lat', '$Lon]'),";
 
}
```

The value for each textbox in the form table is "input_Desc[]", "input_Lat[]", "input_Lon[]".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**'Desc' has been changed to 'in_Desc' so that it doesn't clash with the reserved word. The semi-colon at the end of the concatenated sql statement has been changed to a comma. The result is still the same.

echo-ed the sql statement and this is the result `INSERT INTO map_input (user_id, point_desc, lat, lon) VALUES ('4', 'Start', '53.066363', ' -6.293127]'),`

**Edit:**HTML added below for the table and adding extra rows.
Table/Form

```html
<form action="mapInput.php" method="get">
      <table id="gpsPoints">
        <tr>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Latitude</th>
          <th>Longitude</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> <input type="text" name="input_Desc[]"> </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="input_Lat[]" ></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="input_Lon[]"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Save Route" >
      </form>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button onClick="addRow()" >Add new point </button>
```

Function to add row:

```html
function addRow()
{
 var table = document.getElementById("gpsPoints");
 var row = table.insertRow(2);
 var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
 var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
 var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
 
 //adding text boxes to each cell
 var element1 = document.createElement("input");
 element1.type = "textbox";
 element1.name = "input_Desc[]";
 cell1.appendChild(element1);
 
 var element2 = document.createElement("input");
 element2.type = "textbox";
 element2.name = "input_Lat[]";
 cell2.appendChild(element2);
 
 var element3 = document.createElement("input");
 element2.type = "textbox";
 element2.name = "input_Lon[]";
 cell3.appendChild(element3);
 
}//end function addRow()
</script>
```

**Edit**The values are definitely being passed in as they are in the url bar, however they are not going into the foreach loop and being inserted.

Comment: dude, first debug the your GET data with **print_r()**, and see what u get...

Comment: Desc is a reserved word,enclose it with backticks \`desc\` But it shoudnt add any row in that case

Comment: Also at the end of that loop the problem is you\`ll have a statement INSERT INTO blah VALUES 1,2,3,4, so you\`ll have an extra comma at the end.Use some sort of substring function to remove it

Comment: @Mihai I have a substring function outside of the loop. Still only inserting the first row

Comment: Can we see the $sql echoed out?

Comment: @Mihai added html for form/table and adding rows to the table

Comment: How does the string $sql actuall look like after the for-loop? print_r($sql). I would recommend using $_POST instead of $_GET

Answer (score 2):

You are closing your request on sql concatenation on line :

```
$sql = $sql."('$user_id', '$Desc', '$Lat', '$Lon]');";
```

Replace  **";"** by **","**

And add after loop :

```
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -1) . ";";
```

Comment: I had the "," at the end of the statement previously and it still didn't add more than the first row. Thanks though

Comment: Not a comma at the end, you are in concatenation ...
A request must by look like that : insert into table (f1, f2) values (1,2), (1, 3),... (1, n);
So, you must by add a comma on your loop, but finish by ";"
You can make this with : $sql = substr($sql,0, -1).";";

Comment: I had the substr after the loop already. However, I did add the ". ";"; to the end of it so thank you for that. But the problem still persists. Only the first row is being added still.

Comment: can you paste a here print_r($_GET) from your form processor
you must by pass by POST (GET have size limitation)

Comment: Printed statement is above in post. Changed method to POST and still not working.

Comment: No dont sée it. on a first line of tour script put print_r($_GET); exit; and show results here. Don't change for post method now.

Comment: `Array ( [input_Desc] => Array ( [0] => Start [1] => Track ) [input_Lat] => Array ( [0] => 53.066363 ) [input_Lon] => Array ( [0] => -6.293127 [1] => 53.065950 ) )` is what I get after that "print_r($_GET)" statement

Comment: input_Lat ans input_Lon bas not a same size... Son tour compiled query must ne wrong, show it, comment previous print ans exit and make same with $sql after loop

Answer (score 2):

you query string will end up looking like

```
INSERT INTO map_input (user_id, desc, lat, lon) VALUES ('user_id', 'desc1', 'lat1', 'lon1'); ('user_id', 'desc2', 'lat2', 'lon2');
```

Replace the **;** at the end of the line

```
$sql = $sql."('$user_id', '$Desc', '$Lat', '$Lon]');"; to read $sql = $sql."('$user_id', '$Desc', '$Lat', '$Lon]'),";
```

also change

`$sql = "INSERT INTO map_input (user_id, desc, lat, lon) VALUES ";`

to be

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO map_input (user_id, `desc`, lat, lon) VALUES ";
```

this is because desc is a reserved word in mysql.